# Git add -N <file> doesn't change index

Tags: git

I recently learned about `git add --intent-to-add`. From my understanding,
this flag allows you to stage the file, but keep the file contents unstaged (effectively adding a blank file).
When I use this to add files however, my staging area shows no changes.

```
u@user MINGW64 ~/AWS (main)
$ ls
Beanstalk.md  billing_and_dashboard.md  Certificates.md  IAM_Identity_center.md

u@user MINGW64 ~/AWS (main)
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    aws_notes.md

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        new file:   Beanstalk.md
        new file:   Certificates.md
        new file:   IAM_Identity_center.md
        new file:   billing_and_dashboard.md


u@user MINGW64 ~/AWS (main)
$ git add -N Beanstalk.md 

u@user MINGW64 ~/AWS (main)
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    aws_notes.md

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        new file:   Beanstalk.md
        new file:   Certificates.md
        new file:   IAM_Identity_center.md
        new file:   billing_and_dashboard.md
```

Comment: It looks like you already had the "intent to add" those files? Git is tracking those files already, otherwise, it would be listed as "untracked files." https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPvw0.png

Comment: Thank you, this explains it. My confusion came from thinking that an actual file (one without content) would be added to the index, rather than just a path.